# Using LINQ to select all from multiple tables

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a very weird question to ask.

I have 6 tables that I need to get data from:

```
TEMPLATE
TEMPLATE_INDEX
TABLE_1
TABLE_2
TABLE_3
TABLE_4
```

The template has a FK to another table (INTEREST), which is used as the key to get the data. It is a one-to-many relationship, 1 INTEREST has many TEMPLATE

How the tables are linked

```
TEMPLATE <----- TEMPLATE_INDEX
TEMPLATE_INDEX <----- TABLE_1
TEMPLATE_INDEX <----- TABLE_2
TEMPLATE_INDEX <----- TABLE_3
TEMPLATE_INDEX <----- TABLE_4
```

I'm trying to download all the data pertaining to the INTEREST selected upon loading of the UserControl (I don't know if this is a good idea but my thinking is that, there will be less querying of the database when the data is needed).

I have tried doing this in VB.NET

```
dim temp_listing = From q In context.TEMPLATE _
                   Join t In context.TEMPLATE_INDEX On t.TEMPLATE_ID Equals q.ID
                   Join t1 In context.TABLE_1 On t1.TEMPLATE_INDEX_ID Equals t.ID
                   Join t2 In context.TABLE_2 On t2.TEMPLATE_INDEX_ID Equals t.ID
                   Join t3 In context.TABLE_3 On t3.TEMPLATE_INDEX_ID Equals t.ID
                   Join t4 In context.TABLE_4 On t4.TEMPLATE_INDEX_ID Equals t.ID
                   Select q, t, t1, t2, t3, t4

temp_listing.Load()
```

But not all the data gets downloaded.

Can anyone enlighten me on how to do this?

The reason why I'm doing this is because the database is not local. A lot of times, it takes a while for the relevant information to appear after the user has done something. I thought that it would be easy to have a longer loading time and make the program run smoothly after, since all data will be local (i.e. context.TABLE_1.Local)

If anyone, has a better solution, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to note is that you should avoid the `Join` statement in LINQ statements to a SQL backend. It is verbose and nearly always you can (and should) do the same thing with navigation properties.

I suspect that the problem here is the `INNER JOIN`. Contrary to `OUTER JOIN` it only returns data where both sides of the join are present.

In stead of this, use the `Include` statement with navigation properties:

```
From q In context.Template
                 .Include(t => t.TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_1)
                 .Include(t => t.TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_2)
                 .Include(t => t.TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_3)
                 .Include(t => t.TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_4)
Select q
```

This will translate to outer joins.

A second remark is that generally it is a good idea to get data in one roundtrip. But you'll have to do some benchmarking here. A query with "many" joins has a way of blowing up the result set in length and in width. In the end, you may send an excessive amount of data over the wire, taking much longer than a few separate roundtrips sending less data.

Comment: Thanks Gert. The problem is I'm using VB.NET and this syntax doesn't work. Do you know of a place of how to convert this to VB.NET?

Comment: Ah, I only forgot to use VB syntax for lambda expressions: `.Include(Function(t) t.TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_1`

Comment: Sorry Gert for this but when I do .Include(Function(t) t.TEMPLATE_INDEX the next . doesn't give me any of the TABLEs. When I do the context.TEMPLATE_INDEX. the TABLEs are there. Is there something wrong with me system?

Comment: Well, I had to guess the structure of your class model and the presence of navigation properties. If you could show these, maybe I can modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: The MODEL ID and name. TEMPLATE: ID, name, description, FK to MODEL. TEMPLATE_INDEX: ID, name, description, index, staff, FK to TEMPLATE. TABLE_1: ID, name, description, value, FK to TEMPLATE_INDEX. TABLE_2: ID, name, description, temperature, FK to TEMPLATE_INDEX. TABLE 3 and 4 are about the same with the FK to TEMPLATE_INDEX.

Comment: Then I'd advise you to add these navigation properties. It really leverages the power of LINQ queries.

Comment: Gert - What navigation properties?

Comment: TEMPLATE_INDEX.TABLE_1 etc.

Comment: Sorry to be so stupid but does this mean I should add a FK to TABLE_1 in TEMPLATE_INDEX?

Comment: Always. But how to do that really depends on how you work, code-first, db first. If you need more support in this, after trying, it's time to start a new question.

Comment: Thanks Gert. You've been a great help.